# Creating a private struct type gives me the error "the default constructor... cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function."

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I am only allowed to create add my own data as a private type. Please consider the following code. My error occurs at "newNode = new Node;":

```
#ifndef COACHINGSTAFF_H
#define COACHINGSTAFF_H

#include <string>

typedef std::string IType;

class CoachingStaff
{
public:
    CoachingStaff(); // Create an empty CoachingStaff list

private:
    struct Node
    {
        std::string firstName;
        std::string lastName;
        IType& value;

        Node *next;
        Node *prev;
    };

    Node *head;
    Node *tail;

    Node* ptrToNested()
    {
        Node *newNode;
        newNode = new Node;
        return newNode;
    }
};

#endif // !
```

In the line "newNode = new Node", I get the error:

" the default constructor of "CoachingStaff:Node" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function."

I seem I get this error if I try to allocate memory for a new Node object anywhere in my code. Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: The issue is that classes that have a reference as a class member do not have default constructors. Because your `struct Node` has a reference as one of its members, it does not have a default constructor. You must declare and define a constructor for `struct Node` that does whatever you want it to do. But, in all cases, the constructor will be required to initialize the reference member, so you need to figure out exactly what you intend to do about it. Only you know all the requirements for your program, and you will have to figure it out, noone else will be able to help you, with that.

Comment: Thanks Sam Varshavchik! It looks like I accidentally added the reference symbol ampersand inside my one of my struct variables.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your `Node` class.

```
struct Node
{
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    IType& value;

    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};
```

The node class is storing a reference to an `IType`. It's fine to store references in structs and classes, but references *have* to be assigned when the struct is constructed. Let's look at what a constructor for `Node` looks like:

```
struct Node
{
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    IType& value;

    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
    Node(std::string const& fName, std::string const& lName, IType& val)
      : firstName(fName) //Constructs firstName
      , lastName(lName)  //Constructs lastName
      , value(val)       //Assigns the reference
    { } //The body of the constructor doesn't have to do anything
};
```

In this case, `value` references the input `val`. There's no default-constructor for `Node` because that would leave value unassigned, and a reference always has to be assigned to something. That's why the compiler says it's deleted.

There are definitely cases when you want a class to store a reference. I've used that multiple times in my code, often when defining classes that need to function as a closure. It's really useful for writing callbacks. In your particular case, however, storing `IType` directly is probably the best option:

```
struct Node
{
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    //value is stored directly, 
    //so Node is default-constructible
    IType value; 

    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};
```